# calculate glyphs via icu layout engine

Tags: linux, icu

i am porting a program from windows to linux.
for complex text, we call uniscribe library on windows. i plan to use icu on linux.
1. uniscribe: scriptItem function will split script to many scriptitems as different font or direction. which is the same function on icu?
2. anybody know some snippets about complex text on icu?

thanks
ken

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure icu is a good choice, its main Linux user was always LibreOffice, and LibreOffice just finished porting its text engine away from ICU (actually due to legacy code concerns they seem to have kept a form of icu but only as a bridge to the harfbuzz-ng text shaper; I don't know if this bridge mode is available in general-purpose ICU versions nor if it's worth using it at all).

The current canonical font stack on linux is fontconfig + freetype + freebidi + harfbuzz-ng (and I may have forgotten some). All big Linux programs that deal with text use those in one form or another. Since that's a lot of components to integrate, and since new libs get added as font formats become more complex, they're usually accessed via a higher level lib. For QT apps that's QT for everyone else that's usually pango (except for some apps like Libreoffice that use one-of-a-kind configurations like icu for legacy reasons). And quite often since apps need to draw more than text pango is itself not used directly but through cairo.

Therefore I'd advise at least taking a look at pango-cairo before settling on icu. It's a more common choice for which you're likely to find more documentation and examples on the net.
https://developer.gnome.org/pango/unstable/pango-Cairo-Rendering.html
http://cairographics.org/FAQ/#using_pango
http://x11.gp2x.de/personal/google/

One of the main developers of text libraries under *nix wrote the following summary a few years ago when text libraries consolidation started: http://behdad.org/text/

PS. The equivalent to scriptItem in pango seems to be itemize:
https://developer.gnome.org/pango/unstable/pango-Text-Processing.html#pango-itemize

[linux](/questions/tagged/linux) [fonts](/questions/tagged/fonts) [opentype](/questions/tagged/opentype) [text-rendering](/questions/tagged/text-rendering) [icu](/questions/tagged/icu) [pango](/questions/tagged/pango) [pangocairo](/questions/tagged/pangocairo) [harfbuzz](/questions/tagged/harfbuzz)

Comment: LibreOffice never used any ICU ↔ HarfBuzz bridges, it was ported from ICU Layout Engine to HarfBuzz in one go. The effort did not take that long either, it entirely happened in 4.1 release. The port was so delayed because no one was considering it at all, not for anything else.

Comment: Hi Khaled, you know best of course, I was fooled by the harfbuzz-icu package that appeared in Fedora. Do you know what it is used for? LibreOffice still depends on it

Comment: HarfBuzz has several backends to retrieve Unicode character properties, there is an ICU, GLib and a bundled UCDN backend. Since LibreOffice already uses ICU for Unicode handling, it is natural to use the ICU backend (in contrast, Pango would prefer the GLib backend). ICU Layout Engine is a small part of the whole ICU library, and that is the deprecated one (it is officially deprecated now, clients are encouraged to switch to HarfBuzz).

Comment: There is actually a [HarfBuzz ↔ ICU bridge](https://github.com/behdad/icu-le-hb), but AFAIK no one is using it at moment, but OpenJDK is considering it (they are probably the last FOSS ICU Layout Engine user, apart from OpenOffice).

Comment: the program was based on Qt.      it is a word processor, like word of office. i want to improve it to support complex text. i select usp library on windows, do u know which one is best choice on linux.

Comment: ken, QT is already moving to integrate with harbuzz-ng, so better complex text support is on the horizon  
https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-18980 If you can't wait for it your best bet is to call harbuzz-ng directly, but it's a lower-lever lib

Comment: and why couldn't i find api documents in website: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/HarfBuzz/?

Comment: harfbuzz-ng is *very* recent. Extending it is probably higher priority than streamlining its documentation (besides, very few projects will use it directly without going through QT or pango and QT/pango people wrote harbuzz-ng so they don't really need its doc). If you build it it will probably generate some documentation, it's just not published on the web yet.

Comment: ok, i see. now i am reading the doc of pango.  if i use icu, i have more jobs to do.

Comment: I own ICU's layout engine, within ICU and in JDK.  And I recommend HarfBuzz-ng on ICU's download page: http://site.icu-project.org/download/51  - that said, the bridge seems to work and can be helpful for testing.

Comment: hello, now i am porting it use pango. but i found some functions do not exis in pango and existing in usp.

Comment: 1. scriptIsComplex : i wrote the code to implementate it : uchar->unicode()>=0x590; if match this expression, then it is a complex script. is it right?    2.scriptGetFontProperties , get SCRIPT_FONTPROPERTIES: for this case, i don't know how to get the information of SCRIPT_FONTPROPERTIES. eg: wgBlank, wgInvalid, wgKashida, iKashidaWidth.    3. scriptGetProperties , get SCRIPT_PROPERTIES : i don't know how to get the information of SCRIPT_PROPERTIES. eg: fComplex, fNeedsWordBreak. does anybody know? thank you very much!!!